# MacOS GLEW install doesn't come with CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glfw, glew

I am trying to use GLFW along with GLEW, I am able to install GLFW via the website(not homebrew fine and set up the correct CMakeLists.txt for my project to use it. But when it comes to installing and using GLEW I run into a problem. This problem is that after I install GLEW on homebrew it doesn't provide me with a CMakeLists.txt file. Because of this when I try to configure my own projects CMakeLists.txt file it gives me the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /Users/angelalindsay/CLionProjects/3D_Engine/lib/2.2.0_1

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.
```

And here is the CMakeLists.txt for my project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(3D_Engine)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory(lib/glfw-master)
add_subdirectory(lib/2.2.0_1)

if(APPLE)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
            "-framework OpenGL"
            )
endif()

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/triangle.cpp src/triangle.h src/object.cpp src/object.h src/matricies.cpp src/matricies.h src/objects.cpp src/includes.h)

add_executable(3D_Engine ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(3D_Engine glfw ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```